# How to override position : absolute in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu on top of my page, and after that a `div` tag that uses `a` class as below:

```
<div class="a">
   Hello!
</div>
```

`a` is a general class that has `position: absolute;` in style.
I want to disable this absolute; since the `div` content not shown completely. So I decided to use another class that overrides the position setting.

```
<div class="a overridden-a">
```

What should I set for `position:` in `.overridden-a{ position: ???? !important  }` in my other style?

**Update**: I don't want to edit the `a` class styles, It is common and general in project.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of what you have created....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default value of `position` is `static`.

The use of `!important` is not best practice and should be avoided where possible. Instead, to override a CSS rule you need to use a selector of a higher specificity. Try this:

```
.a.overridden-a { 
    position: static;
}
```

`position: relative;` would achieve what you require as well.

Comment: Thanks for your hint about !important.

Answer (score 5):

What you set it to instead depends on how you want to display it instead. There are 4 possible values (including absolute, which you're trying to override).

From http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp:

`position: static;` An element with position: static; is not positioned in any special way; it is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page. This is the default.

`position: relative;` An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its normal position. Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.

`position: fixed;` An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.

`position: absolute;` An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

Comment: `There are 4 possible values` Ahh, good old W3Fools getting it wrong again. There's many more than 4: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position. Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. They are often completely wrong. Linking to them just spreads mis-information. MDN is a far better resource.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hmm. the only extra value on your link which is specific to the "position" property is "sticky", which is marked as experimental. The others are all global (i.e. inherit, initial and unset) which apply to almost any property. So W3schools are, to all practical purposes, correct on this one, and I think the language used in the explanations is clearer than Mozilla's. (Not saying they're always right, but in this case I think it's more than good enough).

Answer (score 1):

Well, by default it is `static`, so you could set it to static.

Either by adding `style="position:static"` or doing it with css, *after* `.a` declaration:

```
.overriden-a{
   position:static;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `position` is [`position: static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position), so this will probably work:

```
.overridden-a {
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use inline-css with !important. This will override any other stylings as the priority will be first.

```
<div class="a" style="position: static !important">
  Hello!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.overridden-a {
    position: static;
}`

Should do it but only if you put it after declaration of your a class. !important is usually used not so often if your css file is structured good. On the other hand it is used to overwrite any css rule in your file no matter of position where is declared at. In another words it stands out for css rules of specificity.